# JPA Repository & Spring Security - updating object makes password invalid

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to update a field of my user DTO, but every time I update by doing userService.save(user), my login credentials become invalid in the database, because when I first get the user I get the encrypted password in the password field of my DTO, and when I save the user again I'm re-encrypting the encrypted password making the password different than before.

How can I go about fixing this? Should I decrypt the password when I first query the database in my user service? Is that safe?

Edit : found out you can't decode the password (I'm using BCryptPasswordEncoder) anyways. Is there a way to update all my fields without affecting the password?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to update only the column without saving the entire entity?
There is an example of how to create such a query in the Spring Data JPA documentation:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/2.1.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#jpa.modifying-queries

**Addition:**
If there is a way to save only the password without re-encrypting it? If so, you could perhaps try to:
- Obtain the encrypted password.
- Update the user entity (resulting in the encrypted password being encrypted a second time).
- Overwrite only the password in the user with the encrypted password obtained in step 1.

Comment: The problem is that I'm not simply updating a column. The field I want to update is a many to many relationship; it's a set of roles. I don't really know how to go about doing that in pure SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You should use entity listeners.

Look here https://www.concretepage.com/java/jpa/jpa-entitylisteners-example-with-callbacks-prepersist-postpersist-postload-preupdate-postupdate-preremove-postremove

Create entity listener class, implement preUpdate method.

You should inject applicationContext into class. You can find bean "passwordEncoder". Spring use it to encode password.

In pre update method you get your raw password, create encoded version like
passwordEncoder.encode(password) and set it back to the entity.